# String content in javadoc

Tags: java, string, javadoc

I was wondering, is it possible to generate javadoc for public String constants to generate javadoc which contains its content? 
E.g.
For field:

```
public static final String MENU = "menu_2";
```

it would generate javadoc like this:

```
 /**
  * value: menu_2
  */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reference it directly in the comment:

```
/**
 * MENU static field whose value is: {@value #MENU}
 */
public static final String MENU = "menu_2";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use value tag `/**value: {@value}*/`. See this link for javadoc tags: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the standard javadoc tool. **Edit** I stand corrected, thanks @Aleksandr!

I'd also advise against doing this. You should be adding context to the field with javadoc. Eg what does the field mean? Not just writing what the value of the field is. Anyone can look at the code to find out that value. Most IDEs can also retrieve this for you, too. In Eclipse, holding down the SHIFT key while hovering over a reference will give you the declaration.